# Project from PnP Office 365 not working

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365, pnp

I have downloaded a project from PnP office 365, which is a SharePoint add-in to deploy stuff to host site, here's the project:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Provisioning.Jsom

When I run it in Visual studio, and put the site url to my office 365 developer site, it doesn't ask me for any credentials or anything, and when I deploy, it tells me: Do you want to switch the project to offline mode? When I click No, it tells me

> Communication with the sharepoint server failed

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I am putting the url for my Office 365 site as: http://tenancy.onmicrosoft.com instead of .sharepoint.com , that's why it's not asking me for credentials.